# SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE Conditions [+]

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, full-outer-join

I have the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE Conditions [+]
```

What does this keyword Conditions[+] Stands for?
How this query behaves as a outer join?

Comment: The query you posted doesn't seem to make sense.  Given your reference to an "outer join", do you perhaps mean `WHERE tableA.col1 = tableB.col1(+)`?

Comment: I work on MS-SQL using standard SQL. I never seen such syntax. It is just and example of outer join. I want to know how It can be written in standard sql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is old Oracle Join syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE Conditions [+] -- this should be tableA (+) = tableB
```

The positioning of the `+` sign denotes the `JOIN` syntax.

If you query was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.id (+) = tableB.Id
```

Then it would be showing a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`  so the equivalent is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tableB
   ON tableB.id = tableA.Id
```

If the `+` sign was on the other side then it would be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.id  = tableB.Id (+)
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB
   ON tableA.id = tableB.Id
```

I would advise using standard join syntax though.

If you do not specify a `+` sign then it will be interpreted as an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA = tableB
```

it's equivalent is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.id = tableB.id
```

A `FULL OUTER JOIN` would be written using two `SELECT` statements and a `UNION`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.id  = tableB.Id (+)
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.id (+) = tableB.Id
```

It's equivalent is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.id = tableB.id
```

Here is a tutorial that explains a lot of these:

[Old Outer Join Syntax](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Mastering+Oracle+SQL/Appendix+A.+Oracles+Old+Join+Syntax/A.2+Old+Outer+Join+Syntax/)

Comment: @blueefeet How we can write FULL outer join using oracle old syntax like I mentioned?

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. Now I got it completely.

Answer (score 3):

It is not important how that behaves.  You should use the standard syntax for outer joins:

```
select *
from tableA left outer join
     tableB
     on . . .
```

The "(+)" syntax was introduced by Oracle before the standard syntax, and it is highly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

'Conditions' here just means what you're using to filter all this data.

LIke here's an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE Name like '%Bob%'
```

would return names that have "Bob" anywhere inside.

About outer joins, actually you'd use that in the FROM clause:

So maybe

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA ta 
     OUTER JOIN tableB tb
     ON ta.name = tb.name
WHERE ta.age <> 10
```

and there where here is optional, by the way

Comment: Thanks for the informaion. But I want to know how it will behave like
Left outer join, OR
Right outer join OR
Full outer join?  OR

Answer (score 0):

I hate to just copy & paste an answer, but this sort of thing can be [found pretty easily](http://oreilly.com/catalog/orsqlpluspr2/chapter/ch01.html) if you do a little searching...

> An outer join returns rows for one table, even when there are no
>   matching rows in the other. You specify an outer join in Oracle by
>   placing a plus sign (+) in parentheses following the column names from
>   the optional table in your WHERE clause. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT ut.table_name, uc.constraint_name 
> FROM user_tables ut, user_constraints uc 
> WHERE ut.table_name = uc.table_name(+);
> ```
>
> The (+) after uc.table_name makes the user_constraint table optional.
>   The query returns all tables, and where there are no corresponding
>   constraint records, Oracle supplies a null in the constraint name
>   column.

Comment: I tried but unable to find any such keyword [+]. Thanks for your support.